# Referencing a value in a different table based on a unique value from given table?

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, orm, prisma

So I have 2 tables in Prisma Schema. I want the postImage to reference the userImage from the user it belongs to in Prisma Schema format? How do I do that?

```
model User {
  userId       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  userImage    String
  posts        Post[]
}

model Post {
  postId          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  postImage       String
  belongsToUserId Int
  ??
}
```

I've tried using google, chatgpt, copilot, forums and read the docs. Can't seem to find any way to do this.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-many-relations) page not help? It's basically the same as your code. And if it doesn't help, why? What exactly are you having trouble understanding or using?

Comment: No, sadly. If you scroll down you'll see that it requires me to set the userImage to @unique. Which I don't want to. I forgot to mention that in my original post.